# Use getUrl() in form action in Magento1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-address, geturl

I Want to add some new functionality for magento address book page, I create a Form their, and want to add an action via function like Add New Address Form.

> Step1. : I Create a new function in
>    app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Edit.php

```
public function **getImpAddrURL**()
{
    return Mage::getUrl('customer/address/**importAddr**');
}
```

> Step2. : Create a New function in Controller app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php

```
public function importAddrAction()
{
    echo "Hello"; exit;
}
```

> Step3. : Create a form in Address Book : frontend/theme/mytheme/template/customer/address/book.phtml

```
<form action="echo $this->getImpAddrURL() ?>">
My Other fields here
</form>
```

But When I click on submit button I have an URL Like :

```
http://*******/****/index.php/customer/address/importAddresses/
```

And 404 Error.

Please Suggest how can I use this.

Comment: have you created controller for that? if yes please provide us config code and controller code

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala, No just use the default controller responsible for customer address and add new function their.

Comment: you cannot rewrite the controller in `local` this way only work for `block,helper and model`

Comment: @QaisarSatti, Can I achieve my solution using Observer of customer Module ?

Comment: i will prefer custom controller will do the trick for you. follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento

Answer (score 1):

You can not copy any controller file in local folder. 
Instead of copy customer controller you can create same method

> public function importAddrAction() { echo "Hello"; exit; }

in any of your custom controller. and return that controller url fron `getUrl` method.